# Do I need a privacy policy?

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

I just finished a social app that has users create a username and password in order to have a friends list with very simple social features. In order for the user to see all the features of the app I do need the user to create an account (everything is free).

I don't require any personal information (email, address, etc.). So do I need to create a privacy policy, or a terms of use?

What is the minimum amount of legal stuff I need to do in order to get my app accepted by App review? Any advice or experience would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about App Store compliance, not a coding issue. Please see [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/175701)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about privacy policy / terms of use / legal issues instead of directly about programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an app that requires an account you do need a privacy policy (see 17.5 below)

Depending on your features you should look at this rule from the [iOS Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#privacy):

> 17. Privacy
>
> 17.1 Apps cannot transmit data about a user without obtaining the user's prior permission and providing the user with access to
> information about how and where the data will be used
>
> 17.2 Apps that require users to share personal information, such as email address and date of birth, in order to function will be rejected
>
> 17.3 Apps may ask for date of birth (or use other age-gating mechanisms) only for the purpose of complying with applicable
> children's privacy statutes, but must include some useful
> functionality or entertainment value regardless of the user's age
>
> 17.4 Apps that collect, transmit, or have the capability to share personal information (e.g. name, address, email, location, photos,
> videos, drawings, the ability to chat, other personal data, or
> persistent identifiers used in combination with any of the above) from
> a minor must comply with applicable children's privacy statutes, and
> must include a privacy policy
>
> 17.5 Apps that include account registration or access a user’s existing account must include a privacy policy or they will be
> rejected

Comment: Ya, I just heard it different if you are requiring users to log in or sign up

Comment: ahh... alright thanks. My app got rejected for 3 reasons but that wasn't one that was stated. Good thing I found this before I submitted a new build

Comment: That's weird. You might want to post a question about that specifically if you need help.

Comment: @Andy, also please choose this one as the answer!

Comment: I will. Ehh, they probably just found 3 things and rejected it without finishing the review. From all the responses I'm 100% sure I need a privacy policy. thanks again

Answer (score 2):

According to Apple's guidelines, you need a Privacy Policy if you want to access/use

1. User Data
2. Login/Signup
3. Apple Pay
4. HomeKit/HealthKit Framework
5. Keyboard Extensions
6. Contains auto-renewable/ Free Subscriptions
7. If your app appears in the Kids Category

You can find more details [here](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#privacy).

Answer (score 2):

It's required to have a Privacy Policy, when you are developing an app that deals with the following:

- iOS apps targeted towards children under 13
- Apps that link against HealthKit
- Apps that link against HomeKit
- Third party keyboards
- Apple Pay
- Subscriptions
- login and registration

Answer (score 0):

It seems at a minimum you could be collecting a list of the users friends and some unspecified social features.  It can only help the user feel more secure to know that this information is either not collected or not shared…and if the user feels better than I imagine the app will be more successful.  In fact, if you're not collecting any information then this is a potential selling point that you can highlight in a privacy policy.